# PHP Does Not Insert a New Data Into The Table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have made a simple php application which can retrieve data from database and show it on table. But the problem is that ,it does not work at all! I mean whenever I submit the form ,it does not insert a new query to database for some reasons. Also there's no error appearing on the screen so I don't know what is the problem. Here's the full code of my page:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require 'connect.php';
require 'security.php';
$records = array();
if(!empty($_POST)){
    if(isset($_POST['site_name'], $_POST['site_admin'], $_POST['site_desc'], $_POST['site_url'], $_POST['made_by'])){
        $sitename = trim($_POST['site_name']);
        $siteadmin = trim($_POST['site_admin']);
        $sitedesc = trim($_POST['site_desc']);
        $siteurl = trim($_POST['site_url']);
        $madeyby= trim($_POST['made_by']);

        if(!empty($sitename) && !empty($siteadmin) && !empty($sitedesc) && !empty($siteurl) && !empty($madeyby)){
            $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO list_of_sites (site_name, site_admin, site_desc, site_url, made_by, date_created) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())");
            $insert->bind_param('sssss',$sitename,$siteadmin,$sitedesc,$siteurl,$madeby);

            if($insert->execute()){
                header('Location: index.php');
                die();
            }
        }
    }
}
if($results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM list_of_sites")){
    if($results->num_rows){
        while($row = $results->fetch_object()){
            $records[] = $row;
        }
        $results->free();
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Daygotar Application</title>
        <style>
        table {
            font-family: arial, sans-serif;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }

        td, th {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;
        }

        tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #dddddd;
        }
        /**********************************/
        input[type=text] {
            width: 130px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 2px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
            font-size: 16px;
            background-color: white;
            background-image: url('searchicon.png');
            background-position: 10px 10px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
            -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
            transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
        }

        input[type=text]:focus {
            width: 100%;
        }
        #searchForm{
            float:right;
            top:0;
            margin-bottom:20px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="searchForm">
            <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
        </form>
        <h3 style="font-size:30px;"><u>List Of Sites</u></h3>
        <?php 
            if(!count($records)){
                echo 'No records';  
            }else{

            }
        ?>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Site Name</th>
                <th>Site Admin</th>
                <th>Site Description</th>
                <th>Site URL</th>
                <th>Made By</th>
                <th>Date Created</th>
            </tr>
            <?php 
                foreach($records as $r){
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo escape($r->site_name); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo escape($r->site_admin); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo escape($r->site_desc); ?></td>
                    <td><a title="goto this site" href="<?php echo escape($r->site_url); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo escape($r->site_url); ?></a></td>
                    <td><?php echo escape($r->made_by); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo escape($r->date_created); ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php 
                }
            ?>
        </table>
        </hr style="margin-top:20px;">
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <div class="field">
                <label for="site_name"><h4>Site name</h4></label>
                <input type="text" name="site_name" id="site_name" autocomplete="off"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="site_admin"><h4>Site admin</h4></label>
                <input type="text" name="site_admin" id="site_name" autocomplete="off"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="site_description"><h4>Site description</h4></label>
                <input type="text" name="site_desc" id="site_desc" autocomplete="off"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="site_url"><h4>Site url</h4></label>
                <input type="text" name="site_url" id="site_name" autocomplete="off"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="made_by"><h4>Made by</h4></label>
                <input type="text" name="made_by" id="site_name" autocomplete="off"></input>
            </div></br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please if you know how to solve this question ,please let me know ... thanks.

Comment: check for Errors after calling execute

Comment: isset should be like this  if(isset($_POST['site_name']) && isset( $_POST['site_admin']) && isset($_POST['site_desc']) && isset($_POST['site_url']) && isset($_POST['made_by']) ){   }

Comment: and too if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ }

Comment: In which case its not working 1. when you put `empty text` 2. or `with url` type text ? specify

Comment: update, try this - `$insert->bind_param($sitename,$siteadmin,$sitedesc,$siteurl,$madeby);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've tweaked it slightly just to improve it somewhat for you to tidy it up a little and add conditions to each if !empty statement.

Within the insert query your values need to be added which I have done by using '$variable' under each.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require 'connect.php';
require 'security.php';
$records = array();
    if(isset($_POST['send'])) {
        $sitename = trim($_POST['site_name']);
        $siteadmin = trim($_POST['site_admin']);
        $sitedesc = trim($_POST['site_desc']);
        $siteurl = trim($_POST['site_url']);
        $madeyby = trim($_POST['made_by']);

        if (!empty($sitename)) {
            if (!empty($siteadmin)) {
                if (!empty($sitedesc)) {
                    if (!empty($siteurl)) {
                        if (!empty($madeyby)) {

                            $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO list_of_sites (site_name, site_admin, site_desc, site_url, made_by, date_created) VALUES ('$sitename','$siteadmin','$sitedesc','$siteurl','$madeby', NOW())");
                            $insert->execute();

                        } else {
                            echo "Please fill in the Made by field.";
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "Please add a site url.";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "Please add a site description.";
                }
            } else {
                echo "Please add a site admin name.";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Please add a site name.";
        }
    }
```

Then within the HTML section change the name="" to

`<input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit">`